# How to resample starting from the first element in pandas?

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I am resampling the following table/data:

```
Timestamp  L_x   L_y    L_a     R_x     R_y     R_a
2403950   621.3 461.3   313     623.3   461.8   260
2403954   622.5 461.3   312     623.3   462.6   260
2403958   623.1 461.5   311     623.4   464     261
2403962   623.6 461.7   310     623.7   465.4   261
2403966   623.8 461.5   309     623.9   466.1   261
2403970   620.9 461.4   309     623.8   465.9   259
2403974   621.7 461.1   308     623     464.8   258
2403978   622.1 461.1   308     621.9   463.9   256
2403982   622.5 461.5   308     621     463.4   255
2403986   622.4 462.1   307     620.7   463.3   254
```

The table goes on and on like that.
The timestamps are in milliseconds. I did the following to resample it into 100milliseconds bin time:

1. I changed the timestamp index into a datetime format

   `df.index = pd.to_datetime((df.index.values*1e6).astype(int))`
2. I resampled it in 100milliseconds:

   `df = df.resample('100L')`

The resulting resampled data look like the following:

```
Timestamp  L_x   L_y    L_a     R_x     R_y     R_a
2403900   621.3 461.3   313     623.3   461.8   260
2404000   622.5 461.3   312     623.3   462.6   260
2404100   623.1 461.5   311     623.4   464     261
2404200   623.6 461.7   310     623.7   465.4   261
2404300   623.8 461.5   309     623.9   466.1   261
```

As we can see the first bin time is 2403900, which is 50milliseconds behind the first timestamp index of the original table. But i wanted the bin time to start from the first timestamp index from the original table, which is 2403950. like the following:

```
Timestamp  L_x   L_y    L_a     R_x     R_y     R_a
2403950   621.3 461.3   313     623.3   461.8   260
2404050   622.5 461.3   312     623.3   462.6   260
2404150   623.1 461.5   311     623.4   464     261
2404250   623.6 461.7   310     623.7   465.4   261
2404350   623.8 461.5   309     623.9   466.1   261
```

Comment: Add 50 to the first column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify an offset:

```
df.resample('100L', loffset='50L')
```

**UPDATE**

Of course you can always calculate the offset:

```
offset = df.index[0] % 100
df.index = pd.to_datetime((df.index.values*1e6).astype(int))
df.resample('100L', loffset='{}L'.format(offset))
```

Comment: Great. If it solved your problem consider to accept this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: It works for my case. But what is the general solution to make the resampling to start from the first timestamp index?

Comment: @ Mike But this only moves the bin time 50 milliseconds forward. it is still calculating the mean of values from 2403900 - 240400. But what I need is, not only to move the bin time by 50 milliseconds but also to calculate the mean values accordingly. for instance for the first bin time from 2403950 - 2404050.

Comment: @Same - Did you ever answer this question: i.e. how to move the sampling period to start at the first index value, rather than just offsetting the output?

Comment: This question was asked again, and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33575758/resampling-in-pandas?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

A much simpler (and general) solution is to just add `base=1` to your resampling function:

```
df = df.resample('100L', base=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

A dynamic solution that also works with Pandas `Timestamp` objects (often used to index Timeseries data), or strictly numerical index values, is to use the `origin` argument with the `resample` method as such:

```
df = df.resample("15min", origin=df.index[0])
```

Where the "15min" would represent the sampling frequency and the `index[0]` argument essentially says:

"start sampling the desired frequency at the first value found in this `DataFrame`'s index"

AFAIK, this works for any combination of numerical value + a valid `Timerseries` offset alias ([see here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#offset-aliases)) such as "15min", "4H", "1W", etc.